# Script for package installation

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, scripts, dpkg

I want to write a script that makes package reinstalling easier but not sure how to specify input an the end of commands. I have this so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
## Need someway to specify input
sudo dpkg --set-selections <
## Need someway to specify input here too
sudo debconf-set-selections < 
sudo apt-get -y update
## dselect-upgrade gave me issues
## if dselect not installed then install it

sudo apt-get dselect-install
exit 0
```

Any tips?

Comment: So you want to specify the package names as your input ?

Comment: Specify input from what?

Comment: from a text file that i output from  dpkg --get-selections > output.txt (example). Only i want user input as to where that file is when i go to run that script.make sense?